# forfiles and folder exclusion

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need some help with command line

I have the following line which works fine.

```
forfiles /p C:\FolderName /s /D -90 /C "cmd /c (if @ext==\"pdf\" echo @path , @fdate) & (if @ext==\"csv\" echo @path , @fdate)" > C:\Report.csv
```

However, I need to exclude some of CSV located in a specific subdirectories. How do I  update my existing line to exclude specific locations from the check.

For example I do not want to report on any files located in sub directory called reports for example.

Hope this makes sense.

UPDATED!

After few attempts I have managed to get m solution working where I can exclude any sub folders(I know if not the best but it works for me).

echo off
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /s /t:C ^"C:\Users\Default*.*^"') do (
   if not EXIST %%G\NUL (
    echo.%%~G |find /i "\Reports">nul & if errorlevel 1 (
          echo %%G
          )
   )
)

Now I have a problem how do I check if any %%G is older then 90 days. Could someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: why don't you quote `"@ext"` in `if @ext==\"pdf\"` and `if @ext==\"csv\"`?

Comment: Sorry not too sure I follow. I want to exclude a PDF if a PDF exits in any sub directory.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, `FORFILES` variables are quoted by default.

Comment: @TomPisz, I am not understanding you.  If you want to exclude PDF files and only keep CSV files, why don't you use the /M option with FORFILES to just have it list CSV files?

Comment: I only want to exclude certain directories from checking if they contain PDF and csv. For example I have a folder called important which contains important PDFs and csv so I want to exclude them from being reported as older the 90 days. Hope this makes sense

Comment: I would look at using `ROBOCOPY` instead.

Comment: Yeah I saw that as an option but wasn't sure how to do it. Can you point me in a direction of a similar example?

Comment: the issue I have with robocopy is that I dont know the exact location of the folder i want to exclude. It can be anywhere in the tree so not too sure how i can use it. I was thnking about double for loop and check if the path contains specific string and if it does, do not check it for any files. Hope this makes sense.